# Installing deadbolt dependency in legacy play framework 1.2 application

Tags: playframework, deadbolt

I am trying to get a legacy play framework application running that depends on deadbolt.

The dependency in question is listed as follows in dependencies.yml:

```
- play -> deadbolt 1.5.4
```

When I run:

play dependencies --sync

It is not able to locate the dependency.

It's listed at a different location in Maven:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.playframework.modules.deadbolt/play-deadbolt/1.5.4

However I wasn't able to resolve the dependency by editing dependencies.yml to point to what seems to be the current location.

Answer (score 0):

I have since figured this out:

- Download the module from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/maven-play-plugin/org/playframework/modules/deadbolt/play-deadbolt/1.5.4/
- Install the the module in the modules directory for your play framework installation.
- execute: play install deadbolt
- execute again: play dependencies --sync

The dependency loads.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency management in Play 1 changed during its lifetime from reading local libraries to having declared dependencies.  Local libraries were placed in the `modules` directory.  These dependencies were available via the Play website at the [module site] (https://www.playframework.com/modules/deadbolt).

The version you downloaded is the mavenized library, packaged by Grzegorz Slowikowski - see, for example, this pretty old post on the [user group](Grzegorz Slowikowski).